# postcss and simple-vars - use variables that are inside an object

Tags: javascript, postcss

**TL;DR:** If I have an object like this and use postcss-simple-vars:

```
default: {
  white: '#ffffff'
}
```

how can I use `$white` variable in my css?

---

**LONG VERSION:**

I have two projects, one that contains all of my react components, and the other one is an app that uses those components. (NOTE: code below is a stripped-down version and not the full code, which is not relevant for this)
I have a theme exported like this:

```
const theme = {
  ...some other stuff, not relevant to this question,
  variables: {
    colors: {
      white: '#ffffff',
      black: '#000000',
      ...
    }
  }
}
export default theme;
```

and in my app project, I am importing this as import theme from `'../node_modules/components/theme.js'`;
If I log the theme, everything is correct.

Now, inside `postcss.config.js` file I'm using this to define where postcss-simple-vars should get the variables from:

```
'postcss-simple-vars': {
  variables: require('./node_modules/components/theme.js'),
  onVariables: (variables) => {console.log(variables}
},
```

the console log inside `onVariables` method prints off all of my variables in this format:

```
default: {
 colors: {
   white: '#ffffff',
   black: '#000000'
 }
}
```

so in my css i tried to use them in several ways:

```
html, body {
 background-color: $white;
 background-color: $default.colors.white;
 background-color: $default['colors']['white'];
}
```

but non of the above worked (it mainly renders as `background-color: [object,object];`

How can I use the variables in this scenario? is it even possible?

Thanks for any advice and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I decided to create a function that moves all the nested properties into the root and now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Could you please provide your code so we can check it out?